# SQL How To? Select all items from one table, and fill in the gaps based on another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Firstly, thank you for your time taken out to read this and please excuse the title, I wasn't quite sure how to describe my problem.

I have two tables. One for SystemUsers and another for PrintingPermissions.

**PrintingPermissions Table**

**ID**   ----  **SystemUserID** --- **PrintGroupTypeID** --- **CanPrint**
 1 ----------- 22 ------------------------- 1 -------------------True

2 ----------- 22-------------------------- 2 -------------------True

3 ----------- 22 ------------------------- 3 -------------------False

4 ----------- 23 ------------------------- 1 -------------------True

.

.

**SystemUsers Table**

**ID**   -----------  **Name**
 22 ----------- Robert

23 ----------- John

24 ----------- Simon

25 ----------- Kate

I need a select query that will generate a list of all users and their and their PrintPermissions based on the PrintingPermissions.PrintGroupTypeID.
The thing to note is that if the User is NOT listed in the PrintPermissions table I would still like their object to be created but with a CanPrintValue of FALSE or NULL.

i.e. the output of the supplied table data above should be like the following when selecting WHERE PrintGroupTypeID = 1.

.

.

RESULT (WHERE PrintGroupTypeID = 1)

**Name** ----- **SystemUserID** ----- **CanPrint**

Robert --------- 22 -------------------- True

John ----------- 23 --------------------- True

Simon --------- 24 --------------------- False **//-- NOT in permission table, default false created**

Kate ----------- 25 --------------------- False **//-- NOT in permission table, default false created**

Again, thank you very much for your time and please do let me know if you don't fully understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Rob

Comment: Have you looked at [OUTER JOINs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.100).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT su.Name, su.ID, ISNULL(pp.CanPrint, CAST 0 AS BIT) as CanPrint
FROM SystemUser su 
LEFT JOIN Printing Permissions pp ON su.ID = pp.SystemUserID AND pp.PrintGroupTypeID = @TargetPrintGroupTypeID
```

If you want null instead of false, you can omit the ISNULL function and just select CanPrint directly. This will give you three state results (true, false, null), and will allow you to determine which users are disallowed (false) and which are not in the print group (null).

Comment: Likewise to you Esoteric. I really appreciate your time and help. p.s. very quick response.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Select s.name as name,
       s.id as SystemUserID,
       isnull(p.canprint, 'false') as CanPrint
  From systemusers s
  Left outer Join printingpermissions p on s.id = p.systemuserid
 Where p.printgrouptypeid = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I really appreciate your time and help. p.s. very quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've just managed to work it out.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT        SystemUsers.Name, ISNULL(PrintingPermissions.CanPrint, 'FALSE') AS CanPrint
FROM            SystemUsers LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         PrintingPermissions ON SystemUsers.ID = PrintingPermissions.SystemUserID AND 
                         PrintingPermissions.PrintingGroupTypeID = @ID
```